# How to force a Doctrine MongoDB ODM Document Proxy to convert to the 'original' document?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

I have a document Person referenced in document User. When I retrieve User, it doesn't have a Person object embedded, but a Person proxy object. Is there a way to "force" the proxy to become a "full" document (so Person proxy => Person).

I've tried calling a method to retrieve additional data (so __load gets triggered, but the object remains the 'proxy' version.

I hope someone can shed more light on this than the ODM's documention does.

Comment: that sounds like you're trying to do a relationship in a non-relational database

Comment: well, I believe what you're pointing out is Doctrine lazy loading referenced information? How exactly is this bothering your application or the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by [Priming References](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/priming-references.html).

**Example Documents:**

```
/** @Document */
class User
{
    /** @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Person") */
    private $person;
}

/** @Document */
class Person
{
    // ...
}
```

**Using the QueryBuilder:**

```
/* @var $user User */
$user = $dm->createQueryBuilder('User')
    ->field('person')->prime(true)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: This query throw a exception, because after use prime you can't use limit like on getSingleResult().

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to extract the original object, since the Proxy class should be 100% transparent to your code.

If you need to serialize the document, for example to send it through an API, be sure to correctly implement the `serialize()` method on your Document.

If you still need to get the referenced document without the proxy, you can either `prime()` it or fetch it with a separate query specifying the `hydrate(false)`:

```
$user = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Person')
            ->field('_id')->equals($user->getPerson()->getId())
            ->hydrate(false)
```

See:
[Doctrine ODM Doc: Disabling hydration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#disabling-hydration) for more info.